# How can I unnest the "dictionary like" values of one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, after running a script that collect data from a website, I end up with a pandas dataframe exactly like the one bellow:

| id | date | list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | {'date': '2021-05-01', 'data_usage': '200mb', 'device_name': 'iphone'} |
| 1 | 2021-05-02 | {'date': '2021-05-02', 'data_usage': '900mb', 'device_name': 'iphone'} |
| 3 | 2021-05-01 | {'date': '2021-05-01', 'data_usage': '1gb', 'device_name': 'android'} |
| 3 | 2021-05-02 | {'date': '2021-05-02', 'data_usage': '2gb', 'device_name': 'android'} |

However, I need to unnest the 'list' column, so 'data_usage' and 'device_name' would both become columns. How can I do that? There is no 'null' or empty values on this column by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: `df["list"].apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: It worked perfectly when I create a new dataframe like df2 = df["list"].apply(pd.Series). But how can I do that and add those new columns to the original dataframe?

Comment: I managed to fix it:
df2 = df_completa["list"].apply(pd.Series)
df = pd.concat([df, df2], keys=['start_date', 'date'], axis=1)

Answer (score -1):

For one line...

**Try:**

```
pd.concat([df.drop(['list', 'date'], axis=1), df['list'].map(eval).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

**Outputs:**

```
    id  date        data_usage   device_name
0   1   2021-05-01  200mb        iphone
1   1   2021-05-02  900mb        iphone
2   3   2021-05-01  1gb          android
3   3   2021-05-02  2gb          android
```